# Close button on expanded grid item not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid, event-listener

So I have a simple 3 column grid and each grid item has a close button and an image. When I click on a grid item, the image will expand and the close button will appear.

If you click on another grid item, the currently expanded one will go back to normal and the newly clicked one will expand, or, if you click the close button, the currently expanded grid item will simply go back to normal. The way I'm doing this is simply through adding and removing a class with the classList function in javascript.

I have all that working except the close button; it doesn't actually make the grid item go back to normal even though the output of the console log doesn't show the class I add, because it's removed when you click the close button (as it should), so I'm really confused.

Here is my code:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
  const containers = document.querySelectorAll('.container');
  let previouslyClickedContainer = '';

  containers.forEach(container => {
    const closeBtn = container.querySelector('.close-btn');

    container.addEventListener('click', () => {

      if (previouslyClickedContainer !== '') {
        previouslyClickedContainer.classList.remove('enlarge');
      }

      container.classList.add('enlarge');
      previouslyClickedContainer = container;

      if (closeBtn.getAttribute('aria-pressed') === 'true') {
        closeBtn.setAttribute('aria-pressed', 'false');
      }
    });

    closeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      container.classList.remove('enlarge');
      previouslyClickedContainer = '';
      closeBtn.setAttribute('aria-pressed', 'true');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.main-grid {
  gap: 5rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(350px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(350px, 1fr);
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 600ms ease-in-out;
}

.container .close-btn {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 101;
  inset-inline-end: 0;
  margin-block-start: 1.25rem;
  margin-inline-end: .5rem;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 600ms ease-in-out;
}

.container img {
  height: 100%;
}


/* class that is added and removed */

.enlarge {
  z-index: 100;
  width: 150%;
  height: 150%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px hsl( var(--clr-dark) / .6);
}

.enlarge .close-btn {
  opacity: 1;
}

.close-btn {
  position: relative;
  width: 32px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.close-btn,
.close-btn::after {
  height: 2px;
  background-color: white;
}

.close-btn::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  inset-inline: 0;
  top: -.5rem;
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-.5rem);
}
```

```html
<div class="main-grid">
  <div class="container">
    <div role="button" class="close-btn" aria-pressed="false" data-close-category-btn></div>
    <img src="./assets/coffee-table.webp" alt="coffee table">
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div role="button" class="close-btn" aria-pressed="false" data-close-category-btn></div>
    <img src="./assets/coffee-table.webp" alt="coffee table">
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div role="button" class="close-btn" aria-pressed="false" data-close-category-btn></div>
    <img src="./assets/coffee-table.webp" alt="coffee table">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are defining `const closeBtn = container.querySelector('.close-btn');` inside your `container` event listener and calling it outside of it. Causing an "out of scope" issue. Make sure the `closeBtn` variable can be called in places where you call it.

Comment: @icecub Thanks for the reply. I moved that line of code outside of the event listener, but still inside the forEach. However, it still isn't working :(

Answer (score 0):

Let's put it this way... you had lots of mess in a very short code.. I suggest you to experiment with simpler scenarios to better put on focus some notions.

The mess I was talking about it's using variables defined out of scopes and having a better understanding on how event bubbling works.

Once most of the smaller issues was solved, the main obscure fact remaining to address was stopping the propagation of the click event once the close button was clicked. The problem is that since the close button is nested inside the container div and both handle the click event, the event fired by the close button was propagated to the parent. To quickly solve that I checked on the parent click handler if the element originating the event was as expected and in the close button click handler I forced the stopPropagation.

The demo is very very shallow... but it somehow shows how to deal with the event bubbling (if you click on a container it will get red and enlarged, and if you click the corresponding close button it will get back to its previous state):

```js
const containers = document.querySelectorAll('.container');
let previouslyClickedContainer = '';

containers.forEach(container => {

    container.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if(
          window.event.currentTarget.classList.contains("close-btn")
        )return false;
    
        const closeBtn = container.querySelector('.close-btn');

        if(previouslyClickedContainer !== '') {
            previouslyClickedContainer.classList.remove('enlarge');
        }

        container.classList.add('enlarge');
        previouslyClickedContainer = container;

        if(closeBtn.getAttribute('aria-pressed') === 'true') {
            closeBtn.setAttribute('aria-pressed', 'false');
        }
    });
    
    const closeBtn = container.querySelector('.close-btn');
    closeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const closeBtn = window.event.target;
        const container = closeBtn.parentElement;
        container.classList.remove('enlarge');

        previouslyClickedContainer = '';
        closeBtn.setAttribute('aria-pressed', 'true');
        
        window.event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

```css
.main-grid { 
    gap: 5rem; 
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(350px, 1fr));
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(350px, 1fr);
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 600ms ease-in-out;
}

/*
.container .close-btn {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 101;
    inset-inline-end: 0;
    margin-block-start: 1.25rem;
    margin-inline-end: .5rem;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 600ms ease-in-out;
    border: solid 2px purple;
}
*/

.close-btn{
}

.close-btn::after{
  color:black;
  content: 'close';
}

.container img {
    height: 100%;
}

/* class that is added and removed */
.enlarge {
    z-index: 100;
    width: 150%;
    height: 150%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px hsl( var(--clr-dark) / .6 );
    border: solid 2px red;
}

.enlarge .close-btn {
    opacity: 1;
}

.close-btn {
    position: relative;
    width: 32px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.close-btn,
.close-btn::after {
    height: 2px;
    background-color: white;
}

/*
.close-btn::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    inset-inline: 0;
    top: -.5rem;
    transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-.5rem);
}
*/
```

```html
<div class="main-grid">
  <div class="container">
    <div
      role="button"
      class="close-btn"
      aria-pressed="false"
      data-close-category-btn></div>
    <img src="./assets/coffee-table.webp" alt="coffee table">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div
        role="button"
        class="close-btn"
        aria-pressed="false"
        data-close-category-btn=""></div>
      <img src="./assets/coffee-table.webp" alt="coffee table" >
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div
        role="button"
        class="close-btn"
        aria-pressed="false"
        data-close-category-btn=""></div>
      <img src="./assets/coffee-table.webp" alt="coffee table">
    </div>
</div>
```